# javascript scope problem with 'global' arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I know, I know, don't use global variables.  But I've used them for all sorts of control structures over the years and they work fine for this old-time modular 'I object to objects' guy.

My current issue has to do with 'disappearing scope' of arrays that are declared global, filled out later and then referenced from elsewhere.  I often do the following on my main html page:

```
<...>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/arrayStuff.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/printStuff.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript>

var gGlobalArray = new Array();

loadgGlobalArray();
printgGlobalArray();

</script>
</head>
<html>blah blah
</html>
```

Then I'll have something like this in the arrayStuff.js file to make a multidimensional array whose size isn't known in advance:

```
function loadgGlobalArray()
{
<...>
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex] = new Array(9);
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex][0] = currentPathIndex;
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex][1] = currentCtlName;
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex][2] = currentStepbounds;
<...>
```

In the file printStuff,js, I can reference the different dimensions OK:

```
<...>
buffer += "<td>"+gGlobalArray[i][7]+</td><td>+gGlobalArray[i][8]+</td>";
document.getElementByID('output').innerHTML = buffer;
<...>
```

Now I'm working on a new .js external file, and here's what's got me stumped.  Sometimes my old-school global arrays work as I intend them and sometimes they don't. I know Javascript arrays are really objects, and can sort of understand why the *length* property might not be available, for example, but the kicker is that my arrays behave as intended as long as I leave my usual debugging alerts in the external files.  If I comment out all the alerts, the internal array information disappears, length property goes away, etc.  If I put a single alert statement in the bit where I'm filling out the array, *even if the alert doesn't refer to the array itself*, the information is preserved.  Why?

Answer (score 2):

There's nor reason the length shouldn't be available, assuming you really defined the array as you did.  Maybe something else is happening, such as you refer to it in a file before the other file is loaded, or something.  The alert might be causing a pause that lets the stuff load.

BTW, you should look into object and array literal notation:

```
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex] = new Array(9);
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex][0] = currentPathIndex;
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex][1] = currentCtlName;
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex][2] = currentStepbounds;
```

could be

```
gGlobalArray[rawFileIndex] = [
 currentPathIndex, currentCtlName, currentStepbounds...];
```

Much shorter and easier to look at.

Comment: yup, it was a race condition, and the object didn't exist yet at the point it was referenced.  Thanks for the look and the literal referencing tip!